# Disable Touches on a view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitouch

Hi I have a **UIView** who's alpha is 0.7 and below it are some **UITextFields**. I don't want it to call touches events while keeping touches events. I tried using

```
[lightBoxView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

But now the **UITextFields** can become active or first responder. How can I disable it from calling touch events as well as not passing touches to others?

Comment: you can use Controller editing property i.e.     self.editing = NO;
in touch methods

Comment: Do `[lightBoxView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];`, because if you set it **NO** it ignores the touch on that view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to set the `userInteractionEnabled = NO` for all the subviews as well.

Try this,

```
[[lightBoxView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setUserInteractionEnabled:)
                          withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
```

This will call `setUserInteractionEnabled:` on all direct subviews of `lightBoxView` and set it to `NO`. For a more complex subview hierarchy you will have to recursively loop through all the child views and disable the user interaction on each one. For this you can write a recursive method in a `UIView` category. For more details about this category method take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5404950/1407017).

Hope that helps!

Comment: The Subviews are not part of lightBoxView

Comment: lightBoxView has no subviews instead subview are on view on which lightBoxView is also a subview

Comment: @ghazi_jaffary You can use same code on that view then. Anyways what you are trying to achieve is disable interaction on all subviews of that view. This code with modifications to access required views subview should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove those control from tough gesture delegate method.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UITextFiled class]])
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        return YES;
    }
}
```