# Cell's responsiveness in a programmatically created UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uitableview

I have a VC where I created a UITableView and added it to the main view. The table has his delegate and datasource added to the VC:

```
choicesTableView.dataSource = self
choicesTableView.delegate = self
```

I can see the table correctly and everything runs smooth.

In cellForRowAtIndexPath I've created a new UITextView and added to cell:

```
let myTextView = UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, myVar.sW, 100))
```

(myVar.sW is a referenced value token from the screen width)

I added the UITextView to the cell:

```
cell.addSubview(myTextView)
```

Again, I see all as expected.

The Dark Side Of The Moon of this situation is that now I cannot get the didSelectRowAtIndexPath event since the UITextView is covering the cell's view. If I comment the addSubview method, the didSelectRowAtIndexPath is correctly fired.

Is there any way to let the UITextView pass the user interaction to the cell without creating a custom cell view from scratch?

(for your information, in this phase I'm not using the Interface Builder)

Thank you.

Comment: Is the text view editable? Why aren't you using a label?

Comment: I'm using UITextView not for editing matters, only for cosmetic needs. The UITextView has the useful justifying method and other interesting things... :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was pretty simple. I resolved my problem by adding this line:

```
myTextView.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

So the touch can pass through the UITextView's layer and reach the cell layer.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404856/how-to-disable-touch-input-to-all-views-except-the-top-most-view) thread has helped me.